# SQL Inequality in CASE WHEN statement not working due to NULL values

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query which includes the following statement

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0 THEN field1 
        ELSE (field2 * field3) 
    END) AS result
FROM table
```

Which is supposed to return the value of field1, unless that is '0', in which case the statement returns the product of two other fields.

The issue I am having is this statement returns NULL if field1 is NULL.

I want to revise my SQL so that the product of fields 2 & 3 is returned when field1 is NULL, just as it does when field1 is '0'.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0 THEN field1 
        WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN (field2 * field3)
        ELSE (field2 * field3) 
    END) AS result
FROM table
```

But NULL still seems to permeate through the statement and NULL is still being returned whenever field1 is NULL.

Comment: Check for `NULL` first.

Comment: Are you sure `field2` or `field3` isn't `NULL`?

Comment: Your query does already what you want. When `field1` is `NULL`, it returns the product `field2 * field3`. If either of them though `field2` or `field3` is `NULL`, too, the (returned) product will be `NULL`.

Comment: I've just tried running variants of this select against SQLServer, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite databases on SQLFiddle - they all support what ypercube says. Here's the SQLServer variant: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/014de/64

Comment: Thanks - you were right - I was looking in the wrong place for the error - it was the other two fields that sometimes contained NULLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query does already what you want. When `field1` is `NULL`, it returns the product `field2 * field3`. If either of `field2` or `field3` though is `NULL`, the (returned) product will be `NULL`.

If you want to be returning some value (`0` perhaps) when either of them is `NULL`, you can change the `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0                         -- when field1 > 0
            THEN field1 
        WHEN field2 IS NULL OR field3 IS NULL   -- when field1 = 0 or NULL
            THEN 0
        ELSE field2 * field3 
    END) AS result
FROM table ;
```

or simply:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0  
            THEN field1 
        ELSE COALESCE(field2 * field3, 0) 
    END) AS result
FROM table ;
```

Comment: Thanks - you were right - I was looking in the wrong place for the error - it was the other two fields that sometimes contained NULLs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COALESCE / IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) (SQL Server / MySQL)

Easy as:

```
SELECT
   COALESCE((CASE 
      WHEN field1 > 0 THEN field1 
      ELSE (field2 * field3) 
   END), 0) AS result
FROM table
```

Answer (score -1):

To help you diagnose this issue, use something like this:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0 THEN field1 
        WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN (field2 * field3)
        ELSE (field2 * field3) 
    END) AS result,
    field1, field2, field3

FROM table
WHERE 
   (CASE 
        WHEN field1 > 0 THEN field1 
        WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN (field2 * field3)
        ELSE (field2 * field3) 
    END) IS NULL
```

It will become immediately apparrent what the problem is.